# Why does my generic extension method require dynamic instead of concrete type?

Tags: flutter, generics, dart

Given an extension method

```
extension ListExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
  double sum(double extract(T)) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (T element in this) {
      result += extract(element);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

and test code

```
class Data {
  double value = 0;
}

  test("Generic test", () {
    final List<Data> list = [
      Data()..value = 1,
      Data()..value = 2,
      Data()..value = 3,
    ];
    final sum = list.sum((data) => data.value);
    expect(sum, equals(6));
  });
```

And it works fine, but `data` parameter in the lambda has `dynamic` type, when I expected to see  type `Data` here. If I specify that type explicitly `(Data data) => data.value` then compiler gives me an error

> Error: The function expression type 'double Function(Data)' isn't of
> expected type 'double Function(dynamic)'.

What's wrong? Can you explain please?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but if you specify the variable name it gives the proper type definition: `double sum(double extract(T value)) {`

Comment: yeah, you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that when you declare function parameter like this:

```dart
double extract(T)
```

analyzer treats T as parameter with name T of type dynamic rather than paremeter Type.

When you do this:

```dart
double extract(T value)
```

it is obvious for analyzer that T is type and value is param name.

However recommended way of declaring function nowadays is:

```dart
double Function(T value) extract
```

or

```dart
double Function(T) extract
```

so it would look like that:

```dart
extension ListExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
  double sum(double Function(T) extract) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (T element in this) {
      result += extract(element);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```